How to detect if sourced script has been called with arguments or not?
Consider source.sh with content:
echo "$#" "$@"

Then how to differentiate between script arguments:
$ set -- argument
$ . ./source.sh
1 argument

versus source arguments:
$ . ./source.sh argument
1 argument

How can I from within source.sh detect which arguments have been passed to source? I want sourcing work like a separate program - I do not want to handle "$@" arguments, I want to only handle the arguments passed to . source.sh <here>.
I would want to achieve the behavior that when there have been no arguments passed to . source.sh, the script will print 0. Additionally, the script would correctly handle when not sourced.
$ set -- argument
$ . ./source.sh
0
$ . ./source.sh argument
1 argument
$ ./source.sh
0
$ ./source.sh argument
1 argument

I tried reading https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html , checking BASH_ARGV BASH_SOURCE $@ , but they do not think give me the information.

I don't think there's any way to tell the difference.

If that true, then I think I will go requiring users to explicitly tell the script it is sourced, like . ./source.sh --sourced args... , so the script can handle no args properly.

That's what I recommended in my answer.

First! I will leave this question hanging for some time and see if anyone comes with a solution.

Perhaps $- can reveal some info? I get hB if I execute source.sh but himBHs if I source it. Edit: Probably not. I couldn't find anything reliable anyway.

I think that's related to "interactivity". The user could source it non-interactively, or run it interactively. I.e. in terminal: ./source.sh vs bash -i ./source.sh or bash -c '. ./source.sh' vs . ./source.sh

Does the second suggestion in izissise's answer here solve this?

Do you need to execute the script directly, rather than having it define a function you can explicitly call with 0 arguments if necessary?

Workaround: If I source a file, which analyses the arguments, and there are no arguments, I use option --relax.

If history is enabled you could try the fc builtin, e.g., fc -nl 0 0 to get the command line.

I suggest to check array BASH_ARGV:
if [[ ${#BASH_ARGV[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "without arguments"
else
  echo "with argument(s)"
fi

# show content of BASH_ARGV
declare -p BASH_ARGV



This does not work as expected when sourcing from a script.
Tested with bash 3.2.57, 5.0.17 and 5.2.


I, too, observed a difference in BASH_ARGV between the two cases, in Bash v4.4.20.  It contains one element (the name of the sourced file) if no additional non-option arguments are passed on the command line, otherwise zero.

Hi, from the manual The shell sets BASH_ARGV only when in extended debugging mode (see The Shopt Builtin for a description of the extdebug option to the shopt builtin). Setting extdebug after the shell has started to execute a script, or referencing this variable when extdebug is not set, may result in inconsistent values.

Bash does initialize it anyway https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/6794b5478f660256a1023712b5fc169196ed0a22/variables.c#L1705 .

This does not work from another script. So if you make test.sh that does . source.sh, htne ./test.sh will print "with arguments". I think the trick is to [[ "${BASH_ARGV[0]}" = "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]].

There's no built-in way to do it.
You can solve the problem by passing a dummy argument when sourcing with arguments:
. ./source.sh --args argument # source with arguments
. ./source.sh --args # source with no arguments

Then source.sh can check whether $1 = --args. As long the main script isn't called with this option, you can distinguish.

Interesting problem.
Depending on how much trouble you want to go through, and how certain you want to be... maybe compare it against /proc/$$/cmdline (or its equivalent on your system.)
A quick hacked-together test on my Git Bash -
$: cat outer
#! /usr/bin/bash

echo "Outer - $# args: $*"

echo "sourcing inner script with NO args"
. inner

echo "sourcing inner script with EXPLICIT args"
. inner a b c

echo "sourcing inner script with SAME args"
. inner $@

(( $# > 2 )) || exit

x=( "$@" );
echo "tricking with subset - last few args require better logic"
. inner "${x[@]:2}"

The inner, sourced code -
$: cat inner

printf '\n%s\n' "Inner - $# args: $*"
unset tmp myOriginalArguments;
while read -d '' -r -a a; do tmp+=("$a"); done < /proc/$$/cmdline
myOriginalArguments=( "${tmp[@]:2}" )

if (($#))
then pat="^$*$"
     cli=$(tr "\000" ' '< /proc/$$/cmdline)
     if [[ "${myOriginalArguments[*]}" =~ $pat ]]
     then echo "sourced with ~no~ (or same) args"
     else echo "sourced with NEW args!"
     fi
else echo No Args
fi
echo


What it looks like if I run it with no arguments -
$: ./outer
Outer - 0 args:
sourcing inner script with NO args

Inner - 0 args:
No Args

sourcing inner script with EXPLICIT args

Inner - 3 args: a b c
sourced with NEW args!

sourcing inner script with SAME args

Inner - 0 args:
No Args


...and with more than two...
$: ./outer 1 2 3 4 5
Outer - 5 args: 1 2 3 4 5
sourcing inner script with NO args

Inner - 5 args: 1 2 3 4 5
sourced with ~no~ (or same) args

sourcing inner script with EXPLICIT args

Inner - 3 args: a b c
sourced with NEW args!

sourcing inner script with SAME args

Inner - 5 args: 1 2 3 4 5
sourced with ~no~ (or same) args

tricking with subset - last few args require better logic

Inner - 3 args: 3 4 5
sourced with NEW args!


It doesn't really tell you whether it was sourced with arguments - only whether the sourced code has different arguments than the calling script, and this version, as a proof of concept/thought experiment, isn't checking that with a great deal of care. It devolves into hackery pretty quickly.
Depending on what you need it for, it might be helpful. One can hope.
